# Last step in solving partial differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I generally know how to solve these equations, but some of my last exercises has got me wondering, and I don't have the solution, just the answer.

$$
y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - x\frac{\partial f}{\partial y } =  0, x>0
$$

by introducing:
$$ 
\begin{cases}
u = &x^2 + y^2 \\
v = &y
\end{cases}
$$

I solve it by resolving:
$$ 
\begin{cases}
f'_x = &f'_u \cdot 2x + f'_v \cdot 0\\
f'_y = &f'_u \cdot 2y + f'_v \cdot 1
\end{cases}
$$

By putting in $f'_x$ and $f'_y$ in the original equation I get:
$$ 
y(f'_u \cdot 2x) - x(f'_u \cdot 2y + f'_v)=0
$$
$$
-xf'_v=0
$$

How do I proceed here? Usually, I get $f'_v=0$ or $f'_v=1$ and then just integrate on $v$ in this example... But I need to remove that $x$ first, how? Ive tried resolving $x$ expressed in $u$ and $v$ but thats $x=sqrt(u-v^2)$ which seems odd.

The answer is supposed to be $f=g(u)$ and hence $f(x,y)=g(x^2+y^2)$ where $g$ is an arbitrary function of one variable.

Comment: $-x f'_v$ implies either $x=0$ or $f'_v=0$. Since, in general, $x$ is nonzero (what would happen if $x=0$?), it follows $f'_v = 0$ and hence your result.

Comment: I forgot to write that, that was a prerequisit for the question, $x>0$

Comment: Ahhh.. I see.. So easy.... thanks

Comment: Then, you are done! Also, the last statement is not true. The solution should be $f = g(u) = g(x^2 +y^2)$. For example, $g = e^{x^2 + y^2}$ is a solution. Cheers!

Comment: Ok, here we go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $-x f'_v = 0$ implies either $x = 0$ or $f'_v=0$. Since we are given $x>0$, then it follows $f'_v = 0$ and hence your result.

The solution is therefore given by $f(x,y) = g(u) = g(x^2+ y^2)$ which may not be written as $g(x^2,y^2)$.

Another approach for solving this problem is by noting this is a linear 1st order PDE and the characteristics method then reads:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{y} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{-x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{0},$$

which leads to:

> $$
> x^2+y^2  = c,  \quad
> f  = g(c) = g(x^2+y^2).
> $$

Cheers!

Comment: Ah, my $g(x^2,y^2)$ was just a typo.